# How to get stats + games of a specific date using data.nba.net?

Tags: python, nba-api

I am currently playing around with NBA API, and I want to be able to look at parts of games(score, period, etc.) that happened on a specified date. I want the output of what "https://data.nba.net/prod/v1/today.json" would return on any day during the NBA season, but I need to be able to choose the date, as the request no longer returns anything now that the  season is over.

```
from requests import get
from pprint import PrettyPrinter

BASE_URL = "https://data.nba.net"
ALL_JSON = "/prod/v1/today.json"

printer = PrettyPrinter()

def get_links():
    data = get(BASE_URL + ALL_JSON).json()
    links = data['links']
    return links

def get_scoreboard():
    scoreboard = get_links()['currentScoreboard']
    games = get(BASE_URL + scoreboard).json()['games']
    for game in games:
        home_team = game['hTeam']
        away_team = game['vTeam']
        clock = game['clock']
        period = game['period']
        print("------------------------------------")
        print(f"{home_team} vs {away_team}, {clock}, {period}")
        break


get_scoreboard()
```

This is what I currently have, but nothing is printed as there isn't any games going on.

[image: For reference, this is what the output looked like when "/prod/v1/today.json" was used during the NBA season. I just need to be able to enter a date and get this info from that date.]

Answer (score 0):

The data you seem to be after can be accessed using the `https://data.nba.net/data/10s/prod/v1/{{date}}/scoreboard.json` endpoint, replacing `{{date}}` with the date you're interested in (specified in `YYYYMMDD` format).

For example, for games occurring on January 1st, 2020, you'd request the URL `https://data.nba.net/data/10s/prod/v1/20200102/scoreboard.json`.